# execute if statement in variable value assignement powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement, variable-assignment

Sometimes I need to check if a pathname ends with "\" adding it if necessary, the code is pretty simple, something like this

```
if ($destFolder[-1] -ne '\') {
    $destFolder += '\';
}
```

Is there a way to evaluate an if statement inside `()` so that I can use it in variable assignement? I mean something like this

```
$finalName = $destFolder + (if ($destFolder[-1] -ne '\') { '\' } ) + $fileName
```

Given that `if` is not a cmdlet I get this error

> if : The term 'if' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
>   path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a subexpression here (`$()`):

```
$finalName = $destFolder + $(if ($destFolder[-1] -ne '\') { '\' }) + $fileName
```

The expression operator (`()` without the `$`) only allows simple statements/expressions.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake if readability, you could assign the entire result of your if statement to a variable:

```
$finalName = if ($destfolder[-1] -ne '\') {
    $destfolder + '\' 
} else {
    $destfolder
}
```